# MVC Unit Test RadioButton Helper extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, html-helper

in one of my other question I got this really great answer for a helpermethod:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class RadioExtensions
{ 
    public static IHtmlString MyRadioButtonFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex,
        object value
    )
    {
        var isAuthenticated = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            return html.RadioButtonFor(ex, value);
        }

        return html.RadioButtonFor(ex, value, new { @disabled = "disabled" });
    }
}
```

Anyways I'm trying to unit test this:

```
[Test]
        public void RadioButtonHelper()
        {
            var cc = new Mock<ControllerContext>(
                new Mock<HttpContextBase>(),
                new RouteData(),
                new Mock<ControllerBase>());

            var mockViewContext = new Mock<ViewContext>(
                cc,
                new Mock<IView>(),
                new TempDataDictionary());

            var mockViewDataContainer = new Mock<IViewDataContainer>();

            HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper(mockViewContext.Object, mockViewDataContainer.Object);

            helper.
        }
```

When I get to the part of calling the method I can't get to the method.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: May seem silly, but have you added the namespace to your extension in your test class?

Comment: you don't need to mock anything.  just `HtmlHelper helper = null;` would get you what you're wanting

Answer (score 0):

Try including the namespace to the extension as a `using` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

To test your static helper simply do something like this

```
[Test]
public void MyHelperTests()
{
  HtmlHelper html = null;
  var result = html.MyRadioButtonFor(/* your params */);
  Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(MvcHtmlString), result);
  Assert.AreEqual(/* your results */, result.ToString());
}
```